# How to use npm module in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, braintree

I am trying to use [braintree-web](http://app.controller('BillingController',%20['$scope%E2%80%99,%20%E2%80%98braintree-web%E2%80%99,%20function($scope,%20braintree-web)%7B) npm module with AngularJS since I get errors when I try and include it in the template with:

```
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>
```

I have a state called billing that I use to route to my template with the controller, 'BillingController'. I want to be able to inject braintree-web and myscript.js:

```
<script>
  braintree.setup(
          // Replace this with a client token from your server
          clientToken,
          "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form",
            form: "checkout",
          });
</script>
```

Please help. how can I do this?

**EDIT**:

Currently, this is placed a the bottom of my

```
<!-- braintree sdk -->
    <script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/v2/braintree.js"></script>

    <!-- braintree setup -->
    <script>
      var clientToken = removed;
      braintree.setup(
          // Replace this with a client token from your server
          clientToken,
          "dropin", {
            container: "payment-form",
            form: "checkout",
          });
    </script>
```

These are the errors I'm getting:

[image]

Looks to me like the braintree script is not loading(?)

Thanks for the help

Comment: Do you have braintree script in the resources? do you have script tag before the above braintree script?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Please give some more details.

Comment: @Sudheer yes, see edit.

Comment: @Hinrich see attached ss of errors. Drop-in ui is not loading. Styles are not applied.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use `braintree-web` from this url? https://github.com/jeffcarp/braintree-angular

This is module special for angular. Then you should create file like `app.js` and paste this code:

```
var yourApp = angular
  .module('yourApp', ['braintree-angular'])
  .constant('clientTokenPath', '/path-or-url-to-your-client-token');
```

For example:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('yourModuleName', [
        'braintree-angular'
    ]);

    app.constant('clientTokenPath', '/path-or-url-to-your-client-token');

    app.config(['$interpolateProvider', function ($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
    }]);


}());
```

Your controller.js could be like this:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
            .module('yourModuleName')
            .controller('DashboardCtrl', DashboardCtrl);

    DashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$braintree'];

    function DashboardCtrl($scope, $braintree) {

        var client;
        $scope.creditCard = {
            number: '',
            expirationDate: ''
        };

        var startup = function() {
            $braintree.getClientToken().success(function(token) {
                client = new $braintree.api.Client({
                    clientToken: token
                });
            });
        };

        $scope.payButtonClicked = function() {

            // - Validate $scope.creditCard
            // - Make sure client is ready to use

            client.tokenizeCard({
                number: $scope.creditCard.number,
                expirationDate: $scope.creditCard.expirationDate
            }, function (err, nonce) {

                // - Send nonce to your server (e.g. to make a transaction)

            });
        };

        startup();

    }


}());
```

Notice that `app.js` should be included before rest of your controllers, factories and services, and after you angular.js and braintree.js library.

Comment: i want to avoid using unofficial braintree libraries

Answer (score 0):

I think your best hope is browserify. I have never tried it myself but I think the idea behind it is converting NodeJS code into a format the browser can understand.

```
npm i braintree
npm i browserify
```

Maybe try a small test and see if it works?

Answer (score 0):

To expand on @danday74 we use browserify like this at work.

In a nutshell this is how we use it.

So [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) if your not aware its a nodejs CLI that lets you use NodeJs style `require` for client code. It allows you to write well structured, modular client code and build it into a single file to include into your page. Another benefit is every file is scoped to that single file. So no more accidental global's (if your not using strict mode). The only things exposed from your files are things that you explicitly export.

Because its a CLI you to have to install it globally so you can use it on the command line.

```
npm install -g browserify
```

Then to run it simply from the command line do

```
browserify main.js > output.js
```

and include that on your page

```
<script src="output.js"></script>
```

We personally alias that in our `package.json` as we do other things like linting and sass. here's an example

```
{
  "name": "some app",
  "scripts": {
    "build:js": "browserify src/index.js > dist/built.js",
    "build:css": "node-sass sass/main.scss dist/built.css",
    "build": "npm run build:js && npm run build:css"
  }
}
```

Now we just run `npm run build` and it will build out sass and js.

What browserify will do is recursively traverse your file looking for `require` calls, it will then travel into that file and repeat. As part of its search path it will look in your `node_modules` folder. This is why you can include modules installed through `npm`.

Here's a small example

```
//In a file called data.js located in same folder as main.js
module.exports = [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6];


//in a file called main.js
var unique = require('uniq'),
    data = require('./data');

console.log(unique(data)); //[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

What this will do is first look for a module called `uniq` installed through NPM (as there is no relative or absolute path).
It will then look for our own file called `data.js` located in the same folder.

When would build this with `browserify main.js > out.js`

I hope this helps explain what browserify is and how it can be helpful to manage you structure when you wish to include `NPM` modules in the client. I'm aware this won't be suitable for all especially if you have a large application that doesn't use browserify but now i use a build tool like this to write modular code i would never go bacl.

Answer (score -3):

In console do: npm install braintree --save

then in your javascript require('braintree'), now you will have the braintree functions available

Comment: Which works out of the box for NodeJs. However Angular is client side. He would need some sort of build process like browserify for this to work.

Comment: `require` is not typically available in a browser (which is where Angular runs)